# Вставка по уникальному ключу

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Есть сущность с `id` и каким-то другим уникальным ключом (`extId`). Множество потоков (приложений) вставляют в БД сущности с незаполненным `id`, но известным `extId` по следующей логике:

- Если `extId` уже найден в БД, то обновить сущность новыми данными.
- Если не найден, то вставить новую запись.

```java
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED_NEW)
public A createOrUpdate(A a) {
    A b = findByExtId(a.extId, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    if (b != null) {
        a.id = b.id
    }
    return save(a); // hibernate merge
}
```

**Update:**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public A findByExtId(final Long extId,
                     final LockModeType lockMode) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> root = cq.from(A.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("extId"), cb.parameter(Long.class, "extId")));
    TypedQuery<A> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    query.setParameter("extId", extId);
    query.setLockMode(lockMode);
    List<A> list = query.getResultList();
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        return list.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public A save(A t) {
    return entityManager.merge(t);
}
```

Проблема в том, что данный код в редких случаях все равно вставляет сущность с одинаковым `extId` несколько раз. В чем может быть причина?

База данных PostgreSQL.

Comment: Покажите полную сигнатуру метода `findByExtId()`

Comment: А что делает findByExtId()?

Comment: @Barmaley, дополнил код

Comment: Вроде с локами все верно... Единственное, что меня смущает - это `merge` - почему именно `merge`? Есть какая-то логика в этом?

Comment: @Barmaley, код довольно старый. Но в целом вроде `merge` считается универсальным. Для интереса проверял вариант с проверкой `t.id == null` и тогда `persist`, иначе `merge`. Но результат тот же самый. Ошибка ловится редко. Легче всего её поймать, когда много конкурентных поток. Как вариант вместо `merge` вы могли бы посоветовать?

Comment: попробуйте просто `save()`

Comment: И еще как вариант - попробуйте объявить `synchronized A findByExtId()`

Comment: @Barmaley, `save` попробовал - тоже самое. `synchronized` не решит проблему глобально - несколько различных jvm могут вызывать этот метод.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68057/discussion-between-barmaley-and-victor-khovanskiy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если два потока (с одним и тем же extID) примерно одновременно выполнят A b = findByExtId(a.extId, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE); и в БД еще нет строки с таким extID, то они оба вставят новую строчку.

Если у Вас много потоков, то решить данный вопрос с помощью функций save, update, merge не получится, потому что в каждом потоке свой хибернейтовский кеш сессии.

Если у Вас много потоков, но одно приложение, то можно блокировать метод или использовать хибернейтовский кеш второго уровня, который объединяет сессии хибернайта.

Если у Вас много потоков и много приложений, то тут, вероятно, нужно подключать уровень БД - сделать в таблице констрейн на уникальность значений поля extID, если произойдет попытка вставить дубль, констрейн поднимит ошибку, в java перехватить ошибку, найти имеющуюся строчку и ее обновить.

Comment: А подскажите как можно обойти эту проблему?

Comment: "Красивого" способа решить проблему, скорее всего, не существует. Есть не очень "красивые" и оптимальные. Я в таких случаях применяю примерно такой подход: надо создать заблаговременно запись в любой таблице, а перед тем, как осуществлять проверку наличия extID - блокировать эту запись. Два потока одновременно пытаются заблокировать запись, но захват получит только один из них, другой будет ожидать завершения транзакции. За счёт этого гарантируется очередь доступа на выполнение проверки наличия extID. При **очень** высоких нагрузках, такая блокировка станет "узким местом"

Comment: Я написал в ответе как можно обойти эту проблему

Answer (score 0):

Потому что для обновления используется другая команда сессии.
`session.update(a);` или `session.merge(a);`

Comment: В коде я отметил, что save зовет внутри себя merge

Comment: Вы пробовали делать полный лог этого места, при каких значениях и условиях он дублирует запись? Я конечно сейчас может глупость предложу, но что если просто менять b, если такой id уже существует?